# What is used to manage sources files in d3 library?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Today i looked source code d3 (Data Driven Documents) library. It looks very fine, all files imports in one, there is start file and end file. Anybody know how it compiles? I want organize code like in this library, to write my own library.

Comment: There is a `Makefile` at the top level, I suggest you start there.

Comment: They are using Smash, which is an alternative to module loaders https://github.com/mbostock/smash/wiki

Comment: Very fastest answer. Thank you! It is what i looking for.